# SignedRequest information on subpages within Facebook tab

Tags: php, iframe, facebook-php-sdk

I've got a Facebook Page where I've added a Facebook (iFrame) tab. With the Facebook PHP SDK I'm retrieving the SignedRequest information. I'm using this information to check if a user has liked the Facebook Page.

On the main page this works fine and I retrieve the 'page' array within the SignedRequest info, but when I click on a subpage (using a direct url on the same subdomain) I can't access this information anymore.

How can I retrieve this information on a subpage within the iFrame tab?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you only get the signed request when the tab loads the first time.
Best solution would be saving the status of `liked` into a session and use this in the other subpages.

Answer (score 1):

You only get the signed_request object when facebook loads in the content of your website (based upon the url you provided in the app config).  Any linking or redirection within that iframe is now your responsiblity to track. You can do it a variety of ways. 1) Run session on your servers. 2) Drop a cookie and watch for that. 3) Put something on the querystring (but this is hackable).

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I just found a solution that works flawlessly after days of struggle with this problem so I decided to share it.

It's part of the solution proposed by DMCS - session variables.

First you have to store ALL the signed request information into e session variable like this:

```
session_start():

$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

if(isset($signedRequest)) $_SESSION['signedRequest'] = $signedRequest;
 else $signedRequest = $_SESSION['signedRequest'];
```

Then you can access all the information on a later stage (i.e. Tab Subpage for example). Just do print_r($signedRequest) to check how to access the information that you need. For example to check if a user liked the page just do:

```
if (!$_SESSION['signedRequest']['page']['liked']) { 
//Content for users that haven't liked the page
}
```

The important thing here is to store the whole $signedRequest in a session variable. I first tried to store just the information that I needed in a session variable but that won't work. I don't know why.

Hope it helps somebody.